# Lyx inserts and removes words randomly

Tags: lyx

I have a problem with my lyx file. Lyx randomly inserted words like max or plain in my document, changed numbers in my table, and removed spacing between words. It all happened after I edited my work in Lyx 2.0.6 then reopened and inserted citations in Lyx 2.0.0. I didn't change any setting except the color of my note background. I'm using Windows 7.

Does anyone know what could be causing that?

Below is as example where Lyx changed dash to be "Plain L":

```
Figures ([fig1]Plain L[fig2]) plot the fit....
```

Comment: A screenshot and example file may help.

Comment: I've seen similar reports. All were using Windows I think. Are you using Windows? I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: You edited to put that you're using Windows. Can you see if you have the same problem with LyX 2.1 beta 1? Here is the installer: ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.1/lyx-2.1.0beta1/LyX-210beta1-Installer-1.exe

Comment: And if you edit, please add a comment notifying me (use @ with my user name). Otherwise I will not know that you added something.

Comment: @scottkosty I also edited my post that I had edited my work in lyx 2.0.6 (saved it as lyx 2.0.6) then later on opened it in lyx 2.0.0. Could this be why I have random words and spacing in my paper. I have now uninstalled my lyx 2.0.0. though. Why do you want me to try Lyx 2.1 beta 1? Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @user36917 I do not think that 2.0.0 was the reason. 2.0.0 and 2.0.6 use the same file format (413). I suggest trying LyX 2.1 beta 1 because what you experienced could be a bug that has been fixed in the newest version.

Answer (score 3):

Richard Heck here from the LyX team. We have a similar bug reported here:
  http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8854#comment:27
That bug, however, arises ONLY when the file is being exported to an earlier LyX format, not just when it is being saved. Can you confirm that you see this bug when you are just saving the file? Or was it when you exported it to some other format?

FYI, we think we may also know the cause now:
  http://marc.info/?l=lyx-devel&m=138116948207940&w=2